# (surprisingly) python dict "has_key" faster than "in"

Tags: python, dictionary

From popular information and also searching on the net+stackoverflow, it seems that "in" is faster than "has_key" for key lookups in python dictionary. However, my recent experience has been quite the opposite and I have no clue why so? Consider the code of the following form:

```
for f in F:
    if 'A' in f:
        AList.append(f)
        #if f in FDICT.keys():
        if FDICT.has_key(f):
            idx_AList.append(FDICT[f])
    elif 'B' in f:
        BList.append(f)
        #if f in FDICT.keys():
        if FDICT.has_key(f):
            idx_BList.append(FDICT[f])
```

In the above, switching to "has_key" makes the code 50000x times faster even on very small files. This is quite baffling -- does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: No so surprising; you replaced a method call with a method call plus an operator, where the method call has to produce a new list object first. Had you used **just** the operator on the other hand...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's `f in FDICT`, not `f in FDICT.keys()`. Using `keys` builds a list of all the keys and goes through it one by one, whereas using `f in FDICT` uses an efficient hash-based lookup.

Answer (score 3):

```
if f in FDICT.keys()
```

Because you are generating the list of keys every single time you loop.

Try replacing it with `f in fDICT`

Comment: Thanks, that would have saved me a whole day of work had I seen it yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you are calling `FDICT.keys():`, which has to create a key list. You want to do `f in FDICT:`, which has the same result but does not require a key list to be generated.

In any case, I have heard that the conventional optimized way to do it is to assume that the key is in the dict and just catch the `KeyError` if it is not